# ng-bootstrap: NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbModalRef issue

Tags: angular, module, package, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to add the NgbModalRef class to my component but I don't know why it refuses to ineject it.
I have Angular 10.2.1, bootstrap 4.5.3 and ng-bootstrap 8.0.4, I added the NgbModule in the app.module file and imported the class like this :

**modal.ts**

```
import { NgbModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

 constructor(private modalService: NgbModal, private modalRefService: NgbModalRef){}
```

**HTML in the modal**

```
<button (click)="modalRefService.close()">Close</button>
```

I tried to make a function then call the class but same result.

When I try to open my modal I get :

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[NgbModalRef -> NgbModalRef -> NgbModalRef]:    NullInjectorError: No provider for NgbModalRef!
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ModalComponent
  ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        FormsModule,
        NgbModule
      ],
```

Comment: As error says you need to add `NgbModalRef ` to providers list of your application

Comment: I already tried to add it in the providers in the app.module but it didn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, I removed NgbModalRef and added NgbActiveModal in the dependecies

```
 constructor(
    private modalService: NgbModal, private activeModalService: NgbActiveModal ) 
 {}
```

Then I moved the function to the TS file

```
 closeModal() {
    this.activeModalService.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the component declare in the app.module? If not you must import the NgbModalRef in the module where this component is declare.

Comment: I declared the component in the app.module